# Site columns are not showing in metadata Navigation setting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-column, metadata-navigation

I created a custom **Content Type** with some new site columns (lookup columns, getting data from some lists).  Then I created a document library and allow Management of content type in it.

Issue is, when I am going to **Metadata Navigation Setting** of this library, it is not showing the newly created site columns, but it is showing **Content Type** to add in hierarchy and filter.

I add a new site column(choice) in same content type, post the above activity, and now it is getting visible in **Metadata Navigation Setting**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following list shows the column types that the Key Filters control
>   can use as fields:
>
> Managed Metadata
>
> Content Type
>
> Choice
>
> Person or Group
>
> Date and Time
>
> Number

Reference - [Set up metadata navigation for a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-c222a75d-8b18-44e2-9ed8-7ee4e0d23cfc)

Since lookup column is not supported, it wont show in the filter. You can only use the above column types.